# How do I extract both content and their parent HTML elements from a web page?

Tags: python, xpath

Let's say you have a web page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Hello World Test">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
<p>How are you today?</p>
<p>What have you been up to?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to then loop through the nodes on the page and then, if the node contains text, extract the text?

I would then want to organise the text by it's Xpath.

So the above would be:

/html/body/h1: Hello World!!!

/html/body/p[1]: How are you today?

/html/body/p[2]: What have you been up to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath from eg `lxml` library along to iterate over all HTML nodes and retrieve the content with paths if iterated node contains any text:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring("""
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="Hello World Test" name="description"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
  <p>How are you today?</p>
  <p>What have you been up to?</p>
 </body>
</html>
""")

for node in tree.iter():
    if node.text and node.text.strip():
        print(node.getroottree().getpath(node), node.text)
```

> /html/body/h1 Hello World!!!
>
> /html/body/p[1] How are you today?
>
> /html/body/p[2] What have you been up to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you are using selenium.

```
nodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/*")
for node in nodes:
    nodepath =''
    nodeText = node.text
    while node.tag_name!='html':
        nodepath = node.tag_name + "/" + nodepath
        node = node.find_element_by_xpath("./..")
    print('html/' + nodepath[0:-1] + ":" + nodeText)
```